# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'intialize_fn'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I use TFF v:0.18
I would like to load a pretrained network in the inside of `create_keras_model()` So I write this :

```py
def create_keras_model():
    baseModel = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
    headModel = baseModel.output
    model_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax", name="output")(headModel)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=model_output)
    return model
new_iterproc = tff.templates.IterativeProcess(intialize_fn=server_init_tff, next_fn=old_iterproc.next)
state = new_iterproc.initialize()
```

But I find this error:

```py
    new_iterproc = tff.templates.IterativeProcess(intialize_fn=server_init_tff, next_fn=old_iterproc.next)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'intialize_fn'
```

I don't believe that the syntax is error,

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a misspelling.

From the API documentation for [`tff.templates.IterativeProcess`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/templates/IterativeProcess):

```py
tff.templates.IterativeProcess(
    initialize_fn: tff.Computation,
    next_fn: tff.Computation,
    next_is_multi_arg: Optional[bool] = None
)
```

The first argument is named `initialize_fn`, however the code snippet above uses `intialize_fn` (missing an `i` after the `n`).